# My APK is detected as infected by Google Drive

Tags: android

I developed a new version of one app of mine, and then I uploaded it to Google Drive to share link with my phone and some beta testers.
Then, when I downloaded the APK, an error was shown claiming that app is infected by a virus!

After that I uploaded APK to VirusTotal online service to have it checked: result was that just "Ikarus" engine found a "Trojan.AndroidOS.Agent", while all other services were Ok.

How should I proceed? I don't want to risk that Google Play Console refuses the APK
Thank you,
Max

Answer (score 1):

At last I took the risk to upload the APK to Play Store and ... no problem, no notice of any kind.
Maybe Google Drive now forbids APK upload, like GMail.